# Javascript Object o Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to use jQuery to do jQuery.parseJSON and JSON.stringify to take a JSON response and I can't seem to get data that is named as label.

```
{
    "message":"Success",
    "result":
        [
            {
                "prediction":
                    [
                        {
                            "label":"Anta",
                            "probability":0.095694885
                        },
                        {
                            "label":"Mice",
                            "probability":0.9043051
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm trying to use ajax to take the request and try to use it as so:

```
function success(name) {
         var json = jQuery.parseJSON(name);
         var jsons = JSON.stringify(name);
         console.log(json.result['prediction'].label);
    },
```

Comment: Can you try something like this `console.log(json.result['prediction'][0].label);`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Also jQuery.parseJSON is deprecated as of version 3.0.

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: Jignesh M. Khatri it doesn't seem to work sadly.

Comment: aloisdg  I am trying to get the label name and probability value...

Comment: @Lance which one? all of them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access an array by using an index for example 0 for the first item:

```
function success(name) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(name);
    var jsons = JSON.stringify(name);
    console.log(json.result[0].prediction[0].label); // == Anta
}
```

Also JavaScript can parse JSON directly. You should be able to do:

```
function success(name) {
    var json = JSON.parse(name);
    console.log(json.result[0].prediction[0].label); // == Anta
}
```

By the way, you can read in the jquery doc:

> As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

[source](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

If you want to get all labels:

```
function success(name) {
    const json = JSON.parse(name);
    const labels = json.result.map(r => r.prediction.map(p => p.label)).flat().flat();

    console.log(labels); // == Anta, Mice
}
```

This is a es6 solution using `map()` and `flat()`. Check their doc on msdn in case of doubt.

Answer (score 1):

using map method to get all the labels

```
json.result[0].prediction.map((obj)=>{return obj.label})
```